# Raspberry pi - database access

Tags: python, mongodb, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3

I'm a novice at the backend. DB is MongoDB on mlab.com.
A cli app runs on raspi when turned on. 
I'm supposed to come up with an app for raspi where-in user on entering an id, the id is to be authenticated by the app if ID is present in the DB. Pls see if my way is proper/correct me if I'm wrong.

1) Saving the DB credentials on raspi. When the user enters id, the python app checks if the id is already present in the DB.

or 
2) come up with a flask web app or etc that is sent the ID and the web app does the checking and returns respective data?

Is it fine to save the db credentials in raspi?

Comment: Is part of your question missing?

Comment: `Is it fine to save the db credentials in raspi?` Where else can you save them?

Comment: I was thinking, when the user enters the ID into the raspi, the ID is sent to a flask web app that checks the ID and returns back either true or false. By this, db credentials isn't exposed.